# Can anyone tell me what went wrong in this code?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I'm a newbie in Android. I'm trying to scan other Bluetooth devices. Please guide me and help me in finding a solution.
Here is the part of code:

```
scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = Untent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 
    }
});

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);//unregister the receiver
}
```

[image]

Comment: Whats the problem ? Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If yes, paste the exception logs too.

Comment: move `mReceiver = new ...` part to `onCreate` - if you remove it in `onDestroy` it should be assigned in the corresponding couterpart

Comment: when I run on an android device this part doesn't work and I get a force close.. I mean when I click the button..

Comment: Hi zapl,Thanks a lot for the response. The mReceiver= new.. part is inside a button click which is ofcourse inside oncreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is toggle button. Make sure your code is -

```
 mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
 mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
```

Comment: I've already added this permission in my Manifest file.. Thanks a lot for the suggestion anyways.. :)

Comment: Bluetooth is not working on emulater.. And the logcat shows a NullPointerException. So I installed it in an android device. Evrything is working fine unless I click this button. I'm getting a Force Close when I do that.

Comment: @DeepthiG Post the logcat mate.. That helps us to discover the cause of the problem..

Comment: It is impossible to solve the problem until you paste the log here. If it is stopped forcefully, you must get a error log. So you have to tell that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Suman.You made my day.It works like charm now.It was a great help.Being a newbie I cant find out the cause of error. So could please tell me how you found out what the issue was. Thanks again :)

Comment: Look at your error log, it is trying to find out a Compound.setChecked, toggle and so on. But it is unable to find out the proper component class, so that it throws null pointer exception.